# How to avoid repetition of one of several items in array (category name)

Tags: php, grouping

I know there are similar questions here and I have read some of the posts and answers, experimented with some of them, but whether it is my limited knowledge of PHP or the peculiarity of my case, I need to ask this.

I am building a dictionary (id, english, bulgarian, theme_id) and would like to group the search results according to theme_id. I am using `ORDER BY theme_id, id` in my query but I end up displaying the theme with each of the results, while I would like to categorize them as follows:

THEME 1
- result 1
- result 2
THEME 2
- result 3
- result 4
.....

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    //$id       = $row['id'];
    $english    = $row['english'];
    $bulgarian  = $row['bulgarian'];
    $theme_id   = $row['theme_id'];

    $theme_name = "theme_".$lang;
    $theme_query= mysql_query("SELECT theme_id,".$theme_name." FROM ".DICTIONARY_THEMES." WHERE theme_id = ".$theme_id."");
    $theme_row  = mysql_fetch_array($theme_query);
    $theme      = $theme_row[$theme_name];

    if($source == "english") {

        foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
            $english = preg_replace("|($keyword)|Ui", "<span style=\"color:#780223\">".$keyword."</span>", $english);
        }

        $print .= "<li class=\"results-row\">".$theme.": ".$english." = ".$bulgarian."</li>";
    }

    elseif($source == "bulgarian") {
        foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
            $bulgarian = preg_replace("|($keyword)|Ui", "<span style=\"color:#780223;\">".$keyword."</span>", $bulgarian);
        }

        $print .= "<li class=\"results-row\">".$theme.": ".$bulgarian." = ".$english."</li>";
    }
}//end while
```

EDIT: SOLVED, a friend has helped improve my code.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $english    = $row['english'];
    $bulgarian  = $row['bulgarian'];
    $theme_id   = $row['theme_id'];

    $theme_name = "theme_".$lang;
    $theme_query= mysql_query("SELECT theme_id,".$theme_name." FROM ".DICTIONARY_THEMES." WHERE theme_id = ".$theme_id."");
    $theme_row  = mysql_fetch_array($theme_query);
    $theme      = $theme_row[$theme_name];

    // add all results to an array
    $results[] = array(
        'english'   => $english,
        'bulgarian' => $bulgarian,
        'theme'     => $theme
    );

}//end while

$theme = null;
foreach ($results as $result) {
    if ($theme != $result['theme']) {
        $theme = $result['theme'];
        $print .= "<h3>" . $result['theme'] . "</h3>";
    }

    if ($source == "english") {
        foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
            $result['english'] = preg_replace("|($keyword)|Ui", "<span style=\"color:#780223\">" . $keyword . "</span>", $result['english']);
        }
        $print .= "<li class=\"results-row\">" . $result['english'] . " = " . $result['bulgarian'] . "</li>";
    } elseif ($source == "bulgarian") {
        foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
            $result['bulgarian'] = preg_replace("|($keyword)|Ui", "<span style=\"color:#780223;\">" . $keyword . "</span>", $result['bulgarian']);
        }
        $print .= "<li class=\"results-row\">" . $result['bulgarian'] . " = " . $result['english'] . "</li>";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should consider using **PDO** to access the database. The **mysql_*** functions are no longer supported and do not provide you with the ability to **prepare statements**.

Comment: It's hard to tell because your question is difficult to understand, but I don't think you've posted all the relevant code. What's the SQL query you use to put results into `$result`? You described it a bit in your question but it's hard to tell exactly what's going on here without seeing that query.

Comment: Here it is:      `if($theme_id == "0") {
   foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ".DICTIONARY_TABLE." " .
    "WHERE ".$source." LIKE '%".mysql_escape_string($keyword)."%'".
    " ORDER BY theme_id, id";
   }
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you should first add all items to an array and afterwards print that array in a separate function/block.

Right after your second MySQL query, put something like

```
$output[$theme_id] = mysql_fetch_array( $theme_query );
```

and move all the following code out of the outer result-while-loop (`while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))`).

But in fact I would try to put a MySQL query together, to have an ordered, grouped result with all the selected themes in all languages and without querying the database inside a loop.

Or you use something existing, for example this [singleton Lexicon class](https://static.thomas-heuer.eu/snippets/lexicon.example.php).

Comment: I think I've done what you advise but I still can't figure out a way to do this. Here's my code now:    
`while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 $english = $row['english'];
 $bulgarian = $row['bulgarian'];
 $theme_id = $row['theme_id'];

 $theme_name = "theme_".$lang;
 $theme_query= mysql_query("SELECT theme_id,".$theme_name." FROM ".DICTIONARY_THEMES." WHERE theme_id = ".$theme_id."");
 $theme_row = mysql_fetch_array($theme_query);
 $theme  = $theme_row[$theme_name];
 
 $results[] = array(
 'english' => $english,
 'bulgarian' => $bulgarian,
 'theme'  => $theme
 );
}//end while`

Comment: @cheeseus Please insert any updates to your question above and use the code formatting…

Comment: There's no room here for all the code...
So, here is a link to the whole SEARCH.PHP page printed to PDF. The relevant code starts on Line 144.
[link](http://cheeseus.org/downloads/search.php.pdf)

Comment: The above PDF link doesn't seem to work (file is blank) when opened in the browser. Here's a RAR-ed version: [link](http://cheeseus.org/downloads/search.rar)